# scala creating key value pairs from textfile with multiple entries for values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to create key value pairs in the following format?

Sample Input in a `textfile`:

> X: a b c
>
> Y: f g

I want the output to be key value pairs and stored in an `RDD`

```
(X,a)
(X,b)
(X,c)
(Y,f)
(Y,g)
```

EDIT:

```
val sprk = new SparkContent(conf)
in = sprk.textFile("sample_input.txt")
 val tuples = in.maps{s => 
                       val parts = s.split("\\s+")
                       (parts(0), parts(1))
                      }.distinct
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: val sprk = new SparkContent(conf)

in = sprk.textFile("sample_input.txt")

val tuples = in.maps{s =>  val parts = s.split("\\s+") (parts(0), parts(1))}.distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split using `:` and then using `\\s+`

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://...")

textFile.flatMap { line => {
      val Array(label, rest) = line split ":"
      val items = rest.trim.split("\\s+")
      items.map(item => (label.trim -> item))
    }}
```

Comment: There is no ',' in the sample input file and there is no line number. I edited the question to make it more clear.